# System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, soql, sobject

following apex code

```
public String getLastUpdatedAt() {
String timeStr;
DatadoctorStatus__c last = [SELECT LastUpdated__c FROM DatadoctorStatus__c ORDER BY LastUpdated__c DESC LIMIT 1];
if (last == null){
    timeStr = 'Not yet updated.'; 
} else {
DateTime d = datetime.now();
    timeStr = d.format('MMMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a z');
} 
return timeStr;
}
```

is giving me `System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject` if there are no (zero) rows in DatadoctorStatus__c SObject.

Comment: By the way this is expected behavior. If you attempt to assign query results into a single sObject instance, the query must always return *exactly* one record or it throws an exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
List<DatadoctorStatus__c> last = [SELECT LastUpdated__c FROM DatadoctorStatus__c ORDER BY LastUpdated__c DESC LIMIT 1];
if (last.isEmpty()){
        timeStr = 'Not yet updated.'; 
} else {
        DateTime d = datetime.now();
        timeStr = d.format('MMMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a z');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the response in a list and then further do you manipulations.

```
List<DatadoctorStatus__c> last = [SELECT LastUpdated__c FROM DatadoctorStatus__c ORDER BY LastUpdated__c DESC LIMIT 1];
if (last.size() == 0){
        timeStr = 'Not yet updated.'; 
} else {
        DateTime d = datetime.now();
        timeStr = d.format('MMMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a z');
}
```

You can also use `last.isEmpty()` function instead of `last.size() == 0`. `isEmpty()` Returns true if the list has zero elements.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected.You can do 2 things 
1) wrap the query in a try catch block

try{ query} catch(exception ex){}

2) make the last as a list than havng it as an instance of datadoctorstatus_*c
then do 
for(datadoctorstatus*_c l: last) {
if(l== null){}
}